# Yii 2 и Angular 2

Tags: yii2, angular2, frontend, httpbackend

Пишу небольшое приложение на Yii 2 basic - админка и фронт. Так вот, как прикрутить правильно только для админки Angular 2 ? Первое что пришло в голову - кинуть его в папку web и делать запросы к админке отдавая к примеру json(ну вроде псевдо rest api). Второе - использовать стандартные возможности Yii 2, т.е. впихнуть напрямую код Angular 2 в базовый layout, ну и остальной код ангулара писать в файлах представлений Yii 2, также отдавая его в json. Но оба эти подхода мне не очень нравятся. Как поступить правильно в данной ситуации ?

Comment: Предлагаю подумать и прикрутить что-нибудь другое...

Comment: Ну сути это не меняет, вместо Angular 2, может быть Ember например, или Polymer.

Comment: google helps us.. https://nix-tips.ru/yii2-prostoe-prilozhenie-c-angularjs-frontendom-podgotovka.html

Comment: Спасибо, но там получается совсем все сложно. Приложение небольшое, а если я правильно понял, то нужно иметь минум три хоста - один под backend админки, один под frontend админки - Angular 2, и один под frontend самого сайта. Как-то не очень практично получается :(

Comment: В теории так: наcтроить  mode_rewrite так ,что бы путь к админке path/admin  всегда вызывал index.html в папке web/dist/index.html, а в папке web развернуть angular2 и компилировать через npm

Comment: тоесть разработка всегда будет через npm сервер. А на хостинге будет отрабатывать скомпилированые скрипты в папке dist

Comment: Интересно, спасибо. Пошел разбираться.